# SSL implementation for WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, web-config, wcf-binding

```
 <system.serviceModel>
 <!--WCF Service-->
 <services>
  <service name="Service.RestServices">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="Service.IRestServices"/>

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="Service.IRestServices" />
  </service>
 </services>
 <!--WCF Binding-->
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <!--WCF Behaviors--> 
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

Is there anything else I want to consider in my Web.config file? Below is my service interface.

```
Service Interface(IRestServices)
```

`[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]`

When I am try to call using HTTPS then response I get is 404(Not Found), while using HTTP, I am getting response data properly.

How can I call my rest api web service(WCF) using HTTPS ?

Comment: Have you verified the service has an HTTPS binding? Probably it's set up to respond to HTTP only

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy

How can I verify service has an HTTPS binding ?Is there any example than please suggest, Thank you.

Comment: look inside your application pool

Comment: What should I look in to app pool ?

Comment: if `HTTPS` is enabled or not

Comment: @Hrdk: The bindings are on the site, not app pool. You can check that if you are running in IIS - and if it's not set then add it. If it's self hosted, then we could talk of a whole different issue.

Comment: @MarcelN.
I had hosted my service on IIS but I am not able to call web service over https as well as on my Local production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to define factory in our WebService.svc file to support Https in WCF rest service

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XcellenceIt.Plugin.Misc.NopRestApi.Service.RestServices" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```